# How to find substring and remove surrounding P tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, youtube

Wordpress is great but it has a very nasty habit of adding paragraph tag everywhere.

The problem is that even youtube links are surrounded by P tags. And when that's the case, they won't be embedded and it stays a link, instead of a playable video. I've tried all kinds of things to prevent wordpress from adding P tags, but nothing seems to work.

So I want to implement a filter that reads the complete content of a post, finds youtube URLs, and strips the surrounding P tags from it.

For example I have this:

```
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
function replace_content($content)
{
     $content = str_replace('###replacement###', 'something_else',$content);
     return $content;
}
```

$content contains the full content. Now I need to find in $content youtube URLs that are surrounded by a P tag. For example `<p>https://youtu.be/abcdefg</p>`

Then strip the P tag from it and put it back.

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Thanks.

Maurice

Answer (score 0):

Simple and not too good regex but it does the trick

```
$content = preg_replace('#<p>(https?:\/\/youtu.+?)<\/p>#i', '$1',$content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily remove the functionality alltogether instead of fiddling around with regular expressions afterwards (they are [known to cause a significant loss in mental health](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) when applying to the DOM anyway :)

In your `functions.php`:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

See more information on the official [Wordpress website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop).
There's as well a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpautop-control/) for some finer adjustments.